# Keep track of Thread in Executor Service

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice

First of: I'm not that familiar with Threading in general, though I know some of the basics (atleast, I think).

Now, after using the `ExecutorService` to create a `FixedThreadPool`, is it possible to keep track of a certain 'position' in this threadpool?

Example:

Create a new threadpool:

`ExecutorService es = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);`

Start some threads:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    es.execute(new Runnable()); //Implementation does not matter
}
```

Now, what will happen is that 5 threads will get executed, while the other 5 will be queued. Let's say the 3rd started thread is done, so the `ExecutorService` starts a task thread to top up the maximum of 5 threads again.

Is there a possible way of getting the new thread on that previously third position? Or in what order do threads get executed when the service has room for more threads.

I'd like to know this, because I want to implement some kind of 'thread table', in which you can see which Threads are running and which aren't (something similar to a task manager, but way less technical/advanced, just for a simple webcrawler).

Thanks in advance and please, don't blame me if this is a very 'noobish' or stupid question, as I have little experience with Threading and would just like to know whether this is possible.

Comment: Every time you say the word "thread," you should be saying "task."  A Runnable is _not_ a thread.  Your ExecutorService creates Threads, and uses them to execute your tasks, but it is not a normal use-case for a program to interact with those Thread objects.

Comment: Yeah, my bad. It's kind of easy to call it a thread, since my perception of Thread/Runnable is like equal to each other, but they in fact are not (Thread implements Runnable, but not the other way around). Thanks for pointing this out though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> so the ExecutorService starts a new thread to top up the maximum of 5 threads again.

No, it keep the same 5 threads running until you shutdown the pool, even if those threads have nothing to do.

> Is there a possible way of getting the new thread on that previously third position?

With a ThreadFactory you can create each thread as needed, e.g. to change the thread name, or make it a daemon.  As I mentioned there isn't one created, so you won't be told.

> Or in what order do threads get executed when the service has room for more threads.

The pool creates 5 threads before you have any jobs, and they keep running.  There is no free slots as such.

> I'd like to know this, because I want to implement some kind of 'thread table', in which you can see which Threads are running and which aren't (something similar to a task manager, but way less technical/advanced, just for a simple webcrawler).

I suggest using VisualVM.  It shows you all the thread which are running/blocking/waiting etc.  Giving your threads meaningful names is useful. ;)

[image]

> [how to detect when it] "execute a new task".

You can sub-class the ThreadPoolExecutor.  It has two methods

```
 protected void beforeExecute(Thread t, Runnable r)
```

which will let you know when a thread is about to start a Runnable and

```
 protected void afterExecute(Runnable r, Throwable t)
```

which is called when a task has finished.

Comment: Hmm, yes, you are correct about the first point. I didn't mean to say "start" a new thread but rather "execute a new task". On creation I can set the name and such, but I was just wondering if I could use it somewhat like an array (get the 5th preserved thread slot and check that slot's status and such). But apparently, that's not possible.

Thanks for your answer though. I'll wait out some more answers, else I'll accept yours, since it kind of answers my question.

Comment: @PimVerlangen I have added a note which might help you.  I would just use VisualVM myself. ;)

Comment: I think your note is just what I needed: that way I can keep track of any threads which switched status. As for VisualVM: I'm just trying to make it myself in Swing (yeah.. Swing... I know).

Thanks once again.

Comment: @PeterLawrey,  Pim does not appear to understand the difference between a Thread and a Runnable.  Your answer does not take that into account.

Comment: @jameslarge I got that, and I tried to answer for a Thread and for a Runnable.